# view/export/modify a mp4 edit list

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mp4

The .mp4 container format supports a feature called "edit lists" (aka "edit atom" or `edts`) that can change playback behavior without modifying the bitstream. Is there a way to view, export, and/or modify the raw data in these edit lists, either using ffmpeg or another tool?

Answer (score 1):

To view the edit lists of a media file you could use [`ffprobe`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) with an increased `loglevel`.<sup>1</sup>

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel trace trimmed.mp4 2>&1 | grep edit
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f895a40f580] track[0].edit_count = 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f895a40f580] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: 120770, duration: 299786
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f895a40f580] track[1].edit_count = 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f895a40f580] Processing st: 1, edit list 0 - media time: 702, duration: 440685
```

The first index in this case is the video track and the second index the audio track.

In my understanding the value `media time` defines the start time and `duration` the duration of each segment. Multiplying them with `time_base` should give one the value in seconds.

```
$ ffprobe -v error -i trimmed.mp4 -show_entries stream=index,duration,time_base
[STREAM]
index=0
time_base=1/30000
duration=9.992867
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
time_base=1/44100
duration=9.992857
[/STREAM]
```

So this sample file has about four seconds of video that are skipped (if the player respects edit lists).

```
>>> 120770*1/30000
4.025666666666667
>>> 299786*1/30000
9.992866666666666

>>> 702*1/44100
0.015918367346938776
>>> 440685*1/44100
9.992857142857142
```

---

<sup>1. You'll probably not want to parse this, but there may some way to export a stable machine readable format</sup>